# I get the correct result, but in my debugger in the console tab, I always see twice the expected result

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two objects within an array. Each entry is different in its own way. If I now map over this array, I get the correct result in the frontend, but always on my console, within the debugger, always double. Why is that so ?

```
 export default function Kalender() {

 const mitarbeiter = [
{
  name: "Benjamin Koubik",
  urlaub: ["01.08.2020", "02.08.2020"],
},
{
  name: "Kathrin Krautz",
  urlaub: ["15.08.2020", "18.08.2020", "26.08.2020"],
},
];


function Fehltage(mit) {
  console.log(mit);
}

 return (
<>
  <TableContainer component={Paper}>

      <TableBody>
        {mitarbeiter.map((mitarbeiter, index) => (
          <TableRow key={index}>
            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
              {mitarbeiter.name}
            </TableCell>
            {Fehltage(mitarbeiter)}
          </TableRow>
        ))}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </TableContainer>
</>
 );
}
```

In my debugger at the console tab i see:

[image]

On my WebApp i get the right result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are using [React Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) in your Application see `index.js` for

```
<React.StrictMode>
        
      </React.StrictMode>
```

In strict mode component is `rendered` twice so you see two `console.logs`

To prevent this just replace it with

```
<>

</>
```

or

```
 <React.Fragment>
   
    </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Wow. In fact, that was the "mistake". Why is that so?

Comment: Well this thing react does ,you can see for the docs I tagged to get the proper answer